# Make git log «file» show merge commits

Tags: git

So I have a thing happen to me that happened once before: I’d done `git log --follow «file»` and the newest commit I saw was the deletion of «file». However, the file was still in my repo.

Later I figured out that I’d re-added the file in a merge commit (probably one line of development had removed the file while the other one had changed it).

However, `git log «file»` (or `git log --follow «file»`) seems to ignore merge commits when looking for changes to «file». Is there any way to force it to not do that?

I’m using git 2.4.0.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding the `--simplify-merges` flag. Despite sounding like an option that would remove merges from the log, it actually adds them in many cases.

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181681/4757).

Comment: Unfortunately, `--simplify-merges` does not help in this case. `git log --follow --simplify-merges -- «file»` still does not show the merge in the log.

Comment: You need "-c" additionally, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138569/how-to-get-git-log-p-to-show-changes-in-merge-commits

Comment: Thanks, @Étienne, I can confirm that `-c` will include the merge commit in the list of commits output by `git diff --follow`, even without `--simplify-merges`.

Comment: Today I had such a case again and while `-c` made merge commits show up, they had no relation to the changed file so I’m back to square 1 now…